# Replicating Java's AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption in PHP

Tags: java, php, encryption, aes

Have included the java and php code and outputs below. Goal is to get the java checksum value in php. As can be seen I have the same inputs in php as in java  and though I have tried a lot of variations of arguments in php's openssl_encrypt function but not able to get the desired output. Help to resolve this will be much appreciated! Do note that the java code is authoritative, any changes needed would be in php only.

Java code :

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream; 

public class ChecksumGen {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        String data = "INPUTDATA";
        String secretKey = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        try {
            byte[] hashedData = getDigest(data);
            byte[] key = hexStringToByteArray(secretKey);
            byte[] checksum = encrypt(key, hashedData, iv);
            showB64("key ", key);
            showB64("iv ", iv);
            showB64("hashedData ", hashedData);
            showB64("checksum ", checksum);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] getDigest(String checkSumInput) {
        try {
            MessageDigest localMessageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] checkSumInputBytes = checkSumInput.getBytes("UTF-8");
            localMessageDigest.update(checkSumInputBytes);
            byte[] digest = localMessageDigest.digest();
            return digest;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
        byte[] b = new byte[s.length() / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int index = i * 2;
            int v = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(index, index + 2), 16);
            b[i] = (byte) v;
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key,byte[] data, byte[] iv)throws Exception{
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
        Cipher acipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        acipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec,ivSpec);
        byte[] arrayOfByte1 = acipher.doFinal(data);
        return arrayOfByte1;
    }

    public static void showB64(String label, byte[] rawData) {
      System.out.println(label + ":" + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawData));
    }
}
```

PHP code :

```
<?php
$data  = "INPUTDATA"; 
$hashedData = hash("sha256", $data, true);
$secretKey = "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
$ivStr = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
$key = pack('H*', $secretKey);
$iv = pack('H*', $ivStr);
$inputData = pkcs5_pad($hashedData, 16);
showB64('key', $key);
showB64('iv', $iv);
showB64('hashedData', $hashedData);
showB64('inputData', $inputData);
$checksum = encrypt($key, $inputData, $iv);
showB64('checksum', $checksum);

function encrypt($key,$data,$iv){
  $cipher = 'AES-128-CBC';
  $options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING;
  $raw = openssl_encrypt(
  $data,
  $cipher,
  $key,
  $options,
  $iv
  );
  return $raw;
}

function pkcs5_pad($text, $blocksize){ 
  $pad = $blocksize - (strlen($text) % $blocksize); 
  return $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad); 
}     

function showB64($label, $rawData) {
  echo "{$label} :".base64_encode($rawData)."\n";
}
```

Java output :

```
key :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
iv :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
hashedData :ZAgNCUfIbdT9EjdkCb3XDNpMFGV34rXNjcTOQ9cdZ3w=
checksum :9NS/ZKMscpa4V7i2YQQPoycxCwbL1BlK3h9O/1ujoD1iYgjE8tZx+JRGflw5WikH
```

PHP output :

```
key :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
iv :AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
hashedData :ZAgNCUfIbdT9EjdkCb3XDNpMFGV34rXNjcTOQ9cdZ3w=
inputData :ZAgNCUfIbdT9EjdkCb3XDNpMFGV34rXNjcTOQ9cdZ3wQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQ
checksum :LtdJzSl9UgEpZrpdg7X5g5CYqE3eXQvijazrvkw0XFNY2bxn8zGp1ea8DrUmw/uu
```

Comment: Turns out this is giving same output as java :
mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv); 
Considering this function is set for deprecation, how to implement this in openssl_encrypt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out the solution as per following link :

https://gist.github.com/odan/c1dc2798ef9cedb9fedd09cdfe6e8e76#gistcomment-2743227

`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` is not the same as `AES-128-CBC`.

In `MYCRYT_RIJNDAEL_128` the 128 actually refers to block size not key size, in `AES-128-CBC` the 128 refers to key size, i.e. they are both `AES-256` when used with a valid 256-bit key.

In the PHP code, changing $cipher in function encrypt() to 'AES-256-CBC' from 'AES-128-CBC' helps us get the required output using openssl_encrypt.

Comment: could you share your final code, with the decrypt function as well? :)

Comment: Hi @LittleTiger, had to look up my notes on this as it's been over a year. I don't think I implemented a decrypt method as it was not in my scope (this was for a payment gateway so they were doing the decryption at their end). I have created a public gist and have added some notes from my research related to PKCS5/PKCS7 padding as well. Tale a look - https://gist.github.com/siddharth/b114b4415b6791a23ac8196c5a5ef8be

Comment: I have also added the equivalent java code I wrote so you can directly compare the result.

Comment: @LittleTiger Did you ever get a decryption working?